# Selenium doesn't seem to be installed

Tags: python, selenium

Absolute noob here but after spending the past few months learning python I decided today to try and make a project. Simple webscraping project using Selenium which I got working on my Mac pretty quickly. Just now I decided to recreate the project on my Windows bootcamp but I ran into the problem that it keeps giving me the error that selenium isn't installed.

When I run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location =r"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"
driver_path =r"C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chromedriver\86.0.4240.220\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path = driver_path)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\Documents\Coding\Notubiz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Please keep in mind I'm an absolute noob and not at all familiar with Windows but I tried running the pip list command to see whats installed and Selenium seemed to actually be installed though.

```
PS C:\Users\Vadim\Documents\Coding> pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
certifi           2020.11.8
chardet           3.0.4
colorama          0.4.4
configparser      5.0.1
crayons           0.4.0
idna              2.10
pip               20.2.4
requests          2.25.0
selenium          3.141.0
setuptools        49.2.1
urllib3           1.26.1
webdriver-manager 3.2.2
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this and what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to run the code from an IDE or something? Could always try uninstalling and reinstalling

Comment: Yeah I'm using Atom with the script plugin installed but when I run the file using powershell I get the same error.

I'm also not able to uninstall as it doesn't show up between my programs on Windows but when I try installing it, it tells me its already installed.

Comment: use pip to uninstall. `pip uninstall selenium` etc

Comment: When you run `py -0p` what do you get ?

Comment: py -0p gives me: PS C:\Users\Vadim\Documents\Coding> py -0p
Installed Pythons found by C:\Windows\py.exe Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64        C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe *
 -3.8-64        python3.8.exe

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling through the method provided above but with the same result

Comment: just a note, use requests or beautifulSoup for web scraping, its much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the issue.
After switching to PyCharm from Atom everything seemed to be working fine.